# 'Tuple' object is not callable - Python

Tags: python, object, pygame, tuples, callable

I'm using pygame and I'm using a function that set the selected position of a text
in PyGame :

```py
def textPos(YPos , TextSize):
    TextPosition.center(60,YPos)
    print("Size : " + TextSize)
```

but when I run the program, I get an error:

```
TextPosition.center(60,YPos) : TypeError : 'Tuple' object is not callable
```

There's a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `TextPosition`? Is it a [pygame.Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)? If yes, then it has to be `TextPosition.center = (60,YPos)`

Comment: Where is `TextPosition` defined? Is it part of `pygame`? I could not find reference to it.

Comment: textToWrite = font.render("MyText", True,white,black)
TextPosition = textToWrite.get_rect()

Comment: @Rabbid76 answered your question. It would be better put in an answer now that we know that TextPosition is indeed the rect() object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Tuple' object is not callable error means you are treating a data structure as a function and trying to run a method on it. `TextPosition.center` is a tuple data structure not a function and you are calling it as a method. If you are trying to access an element in `TextPosition.Center`, use square brackets `[]`

For example:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3]
bar = (4, 5, 6)

# trying to access the third element with the wrong syntax
foo(2) --> 'List' object is not callable
bar(2) --> 'Tuple' object is not callable

# what I really needed was
foo[2]
bar[2]
```

Comment: How could you give an answer when a question is incomplete? Your answer is not completely related to the question.

Comment: Yeah, very bad practice. If you weren't new, I'd downvoted you. @Roshan is right. Also, an answer is already given in a first comment to the Q.

Comment: Finally i have the solution . Now it works , Thanks !